# How do I write a Query in G Sheets with multiple criteria, which also references a cell?

Tags: sql, date, google-sheets, dropdown, google-query-language

I am trying to write a Query in Google Sheets using the following formula:

`=QUERY(Input!A2:AD,"SELECT Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col12, Col13 WHERE Col12 > 200 AND Col30 = '"&B3&"' ORDER BY Col13 DESC LIMIT 10")`

I have also tried:

`=QUERY(Input!A2:AD,"SELECT A, D, E, F, G, L, M WHERE L > 200 AND AD = '"&B3&"' ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 10")`

Can anyone help with where I am going wrong please?

Thanks!

I tried the two formulas listed above.

I was expecting the formula to produce a list of 10 results, ranked in order highest to lowest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({Input!A2:AD}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col12,Col13 
  where Col12 > 200 
    and Col30 = '"&TO_TEXT(B3)&"' 
  order by Col13 desc 
  limit 10", )
```

assuming `Col30` is formatted as plain text and not as a valid date

if `Col30` contains valid dates try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({Input!A2:AD, TEXT(Input!AD2:AD, "mmmm e")}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col12,Col13 
  where Col12 > 200 
    and Col31 = '"&TO_TEXT(B3)&"' 
  order by Col13 desc 
  limit 10", ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that AD column has numbers in it??, then you can remove the single quotations mark before and after *"&B3&"*

(Just FYI: If you use Col1, Col2, you should set the range between: {Input!A2:A})

Comment: Column AD contains month and year in the format October 2022, November 2022 etc. Unfortunately removing the single quotation marks didn't resolve the issue

Comment: @Dan87 that's still probably a number. Test your query by putting it against true text and I'll bet it will work. I tested your formula against some sample data I had in the quotes was the only issue.

Comment: If both AD and B3 are actual dates you can set it like this: =QUERY(Input!A2:AD,"SELECT A, D, E, F, G, L, M WHERE L > 200 AND AD = date '"&text(B3,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 10")

Comment: @pgSystemTester if I replace the term '"&B3&"' with 'October 2022', the formula works, but I would like to make it dynamic by using a drop down in cell B3

Comment: @Martín Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Dan87 that's because your `b3` isn't text, it's probably a value of October, 1 2022 (44,835). Try using this formula to convert it `=TEXT(B3,"MMMM YYYY")` and then reference that.

Comment: What about then: =QUERY(Input!A2:AD,"SELECT A, D, E, F, G, L, M WHERE L > 200 AND AD = '"&TEXT(B3,"MMMM-YYYY")&"' ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 10")

Comment: That would be what @pgSystemTester established at the same time as me, and inside the query itself